# twitter4j location filter error

Tags: scala, twitter, twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api

I'm using `scala` and `twitter4j` to extract tweets. I'm following [this](https://bcomposes.wordpress.com/2013/02/09/using-twitter4j-with-scala-to-access-streaming-tweets/) tutorial. I did exactly the same for the location as mentioned in the example as:

```
    val austinBox = Array(Array(-97.8,30.25),Array(-97.65,30.35))
    twitterStream.filter(new FilterQuery().locations(austinBox))
```

I'm getting this error as:

```
    Error:(64, 54) type mismatch;
    found   : Array[Array[Double]]
    required: Array[Double]
```

I changed the value to `Array[Double]` as:

```
    val austinBox = Array(-97.8,30.25)
    twitterStream.filter(new FilterQuery().locations(austinBox))
```

Now i'm getting `406 error code` which is returned only when the search format is not accepted.
Any help would be highly useful.

Answer (score 1):

please check your twitter4j version. it looks like the current version (>+=4.0.X) is still under development. So using 3.0.5 will make the code working.